# How to Return the Value of a Promise outside a Class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I have 2 classes. One that sets up a promise and another one that gets the result of the promise.

Food

```
export class Food  {
  constructor(initialSettings) {
    super(initialSettings);
    this.foodList = initialSettings.foodListInfo;
  } 

  getFoodListCodes() {
    return Promise.resolve(this.foodList.codes)
  }

  getFoodCode(code){
    return this.getFoodListCodes().then(response => {
     const theResponse = response;
     return theResponse[code]
    })
  }
}
```

If I were to add a debugger in the Food class, I'm able to confirm that a response is made: [image]

Container

```
...
const codeValue = food.getFoodCode(1);
```

The problem is when I call it in the class above I get a pending promise [image].

I know the issue is coming from how I'm calling the `getFoodCode` method. Would I need to call an await in the Container class to get the response? Ideally I would like that to be contained in the Food class but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: Why are you using promises here instead of just returning the data directly.  It appears like you already have the data so no asynchronous operations are used to fetch the data so no promises would be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise approach :-

```
  getFoodCode(code){
    return this.getFoodListCodes().then(response => {
     const theResponse = response;
     return theResponse[code]
    })
  }
```

When you are returning from a promise, the result is wrapped inside a promise implicitly and so that's why you are getting a Promise object when calling the method on the object.

The async/await approach :-

```
  async getFoodCode(code){
    let theResponse = await this.getFoodListCodes();
    return theResponse[code]
  }
```

Here also the result is implicitly wrapped in a promise so the same result.

Your only way is that you do this operation either by using `food.getFoodCode(1).then(....` or `await food.getFoodCode(1);` inside async function.

To move `getFoodCode()` outside your Food class you can do the following :-

```
const getFoodCode = function(code){
    return this.getFoodListCodes().then(response => {
     // do whatever with the response
    })
  }
getFoodCode.call(food,7);
```

The only difference is that now `getFoodCode` is not a property in `Food.prototype` but rather a function in global scope.

Comment: I have a question, can I move the getFoodCode method outside of the Food class and into the container? That way I don't need to call .then twice

Comment: @lost9123193 I updated the answer. See if that is something you require.

Comment: Thanks! where does the food value in the .call method come from? 

I basically have a list of ids that I need to generate a code for on a table. I understand that const getFoodCode will return the value I'm interested in, i'm guessing the call is the async part?

Comment: That food is just an object constructed using your Food class. The call is one of the methods to call a function with a context as 1st parameter and other parameters as arguments separated by commas. There is also an apply method if you want to pass arguments as array. The only reason I did this was to get the function outside your Food class and call it with any context/object as needed. The function call will still be asynchronous but maybe now you don't need to return a response from the promise and can just do the operation right there. That's all I can infer from the question shared.

Comment: Ahh! That makes sense. I was under the impression that I could call currFoodCode = getFoodCode.call(food,7) and do additional calculations of currFoodCode outside the method but it sounds like I should be making those changes inside the return. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning a promise.  It's not returning the value directly (though it appears you could return it directly).

The ONLY way for a caller to get a value out of that promise is with `.then()` or with `await`.  Those are your two options.

Such as:

```
// this would have to be inside an async function
const codeValue = await food.getFoodCode(1);
```

or

```
food.getFoodCode(1).then(codeValue => {
     // use codeValue here
     console.log(codeValue);
});
```

> Would I need to call an await in the Container class to get the response?

Yes.  Or use `.then()`.

> Ideally I would like that to be contained in the Food class but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

You can't.  Once your operation is promise-based, there's no synchronous way to get the result out and directly return that value.  The caller must use `.then()` or `await` to get the value out of the promise.

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood is, you want that specific food object using that code.. and since it returns promise so you need to use .then()

You can also refer below article:
https://dev.to/ramonak/javascript-how-to-access-the-return-value-of-a-promise-object-1bck

fiddle [you can check here](https://jsfiddle.net/ajinkyaJsFiddle/ekyuov8x/39/)

JS:

```
class Food  {
  constructor(initialSettings) {
    this.foodList = initialSettings.foodListInfo;
  } 

  getFoodListCodes() {
    return Promise.resolve(this.foodList);
  }

  getFoodCode(code){
  return this.getFoodListCodes().then((response) => {
      return response[code];
    })
  }
}

var food = new Food({foodListInfo: {1: {name: 'food1'}, 2: {name: 'food2'}, 3: {name: 'food3'}, 4: {name: 'food4'}, 5: {name: 'food5'}}});

var div = document.getElementById('output');
food.getFoodCode(1).then((codeValue) => {
    console.log(codeValue);
    div.innerHTML = codeValue.name;
});
```